# Using PHP Increment and Conditional Statement to Alternate Loop Background

Tags: css, loop, conditional-content

I'm trying to alternate the background on a theme page that is displaying a custom loop:

```
$args = array( 'post-type' => 'portfolio', 'posts_per_page' => 10 );
                        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
                        $count = 0;
                        while ($loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

<div class="wrapper <?php if(++$count%2==0) echo 'grey-box'; else echo 'white-box'; ?>">

<div class="portfolio-picture <?php if(++$count%2==0) echo 'portfolio-grey-box'; else echo 'portfolio-white-box'; ?>">

                        <?php $videocode = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'video-embed-code', true); //is the custom field being used?

                        if ($videos) {

                            echo $videocode;

                        }

                        else

                        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                            the_post_thumbnail('portfolio-picture');

                        };

                        ?>

                    </div>



                    <div class="portfolio-description">

                        <p><strong><?php the_title(); ?></strong></p>


                        <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>


                </div>

                <div class="clear"></div>

            </div>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
```

But the styles don't seem to change.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're incrementing `$count` twice in every iteration of the loop, the first `if` will always be false and the second will always be true.